# what's wrong with this regex /^[\p{L}\p{N}. -/\\]+$/u

Tags: php, regex

When using this regex `/^[\p{L}\p{N}. -/\\]+$/u` in php I get an 'internal error while using the pattern' error. It want the matched string to be able to contain backslashes.

Comment: What is the pattern you want to match?

Comment: Needs more backslashes. The `/` should be escaped, and the \\ twice if written in a PHP string. If the error really says "internal error" there might be an incompatibility with your `PCRE_VERSION` however.

Comment: `-/` should be escaped to `\-\/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str = '\\';    // = \
$str = '\\\\';  // = \\ (this is what you need for your regex)
```

So, knowing that, your current regex compiles to:

```
/^[\p{L}\p{N}. -/\]+$/u
```

which escapes the "]" character and breaks the regex.

Also your delimiter character "/" and "-" should be escaped inside the regex.

Corrected version:

```
$regex = '/^[\p{L}\p{N}. \\-\\/\\\\]+$/u';
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to escape the `/` char in the class character or use another delimiter than `/`.

Also escape the `-` or put it at the begining or at the end of the char class.

```
/^[\p{L}\p{N}. \-\/\\]+$/u

#^[\p{L}\p{N}. /\\-]+$#u
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your pattern should look like this:

```
/^[\p{L}\p{N}. -\/\\\]+$/u
```

You forgot to escape / and \ characters in regex pattern, using .

Answer (score -1):

Curly braces (`{}`) are used to set occurences of the pattern. Inside braces should be integers. Also, `\p` is not valid pattern and you have to escape `\` and `/` with `\` in regex.

So, if you intend to match `\` followed by `p`, it should be `\\p`.

And, it completely confuses me, why do you have `[]` around regex? Is it intended to be a character group? If so, why do you have two `{}` inside it?

So, what's the string you want to match with this pattern?